# JavaScript Regex: accept only space and letters from all languages

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to create a regex that will match only space and letters but this must include letters from all languages such as chinese, japanese, korean, arabic, etc. Most guides would direct me to http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html but I haven't found a way to make it work.

Comment: Use [XRegExp](http://xregexp.com/) library along with [Unicode Base plugin](http://xregexp.com/plugins/#unicode) to match by unicode properties. 'Regular' JS RegExp object is way too limited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[XRegExp](http://xregexp.com/)**:

In comments, [raina77ow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1229023/raina77ow), suggested [XRegExp](http://xregexp.com/) and the [Unicode plugin](http://xregexp.com/plugins/#unicode) for it. This package and plugin appear to be a robust, and significant addition to regular expressions in JavaScript. You will probably also need [Categories 1.2.0](http://xregexp.com/addons/unicode/unicode-categories.js).

**Stand alone definitions of Unicode character types**:

I adapted a version from the net to use in a project.

Within the Unicode object, you want `Unicode.letterAndSpaceRegEx`:

```
/* From:
    http://difnet.com.br/opensource/unicode_hack.js
    It has been significantly modified.
    Modifications are copyright 2014 Makyen and released under the MPL 2.0.
        This Source Code Form is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public
        License, v. 2.0. If a copy of the MPL was not distributed with this
        file, You can obtain one at http://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/.
*/
/*! unicode_hack.js
    Copyright (C) 2010-2012  Marcelo Gibson de Castro Gonçalves. All rights reserved.

    Copying and distribution of this file, with or without modification,
    are permitted in any medium without royalty provided the copyright
    notice and this notice are preserved.  This file is offered as-is,
    without any warranty.
*/
Unicode = {
    /* Strings to match Unicode characters in the BMP according to their Unicode category.
       Extracted from Unicode specification, version 5.0.0, source:
       http://unicode.org/versions/Unicode5.0.0/
    */
    /*
        Abbr    Long                Description
        Lu  Uppercase_Letter        an uppercase letter
        Ll  Lowercase_Letter        a lowercase letter
        Lt  Titlecase_Letter        a digraphic character, with first part uppercase
        LC  Cased_Letter            Lu | Ll | Lt
        Lm  Modifier_Letter         a modifier letter
        Lo  Other_Letter            other letters, including syllables and ideographs
        L   Letter                  Lu | Ll | Lt | Lm | Lo
        Mn  Nonspacing_Mark         a nonspacing combining mark (zero advance width)
        Mc  Spacing_Mark            a spacing combining mark (positive advance width)
        Me  Enclosing_Mark          an enclosing combining mark
        M   Mark                    Mn | Mc | Me
        Nd  Decimal_Number          a decimal digit
        Nl  Letter_Number           a letterlike numeric character
        No  Other_Number            a numeric character of other type
        N   Number                  Nd | Nl | No
        Pc  Connector_Punctuation   a connecting punctuation mark, like a tie
        Pd  Dash_Punctuation        a dash or hyphen punctuation mark
        Ps  Open_Punctuation        an opening punctuation mark (of a pair)
        Pe  Close_Punctuation       a closing punctuation mark (of a pair)
        Pi  Initial_Punctuation     an initial quotation mark
        Pf  Final_Punctuation       a final quotation mark
        Po  Other_Punctuation       a punctuation mark of other type
        P   Punctuation             Pc | Pd | Ps | Pe | Pi | Pf | Po
        Sm  Math_Symbol             a symbol of mathematical use
        Sc  Currency_Symbol         a currency sign
        Sk  Modifier_Symbol         a non-letterlike modifier symbol
        So  Other_Symbol            a symbol of other type
        S   Symbol                  Sm | Sc | Sk | So
        Zs  Space_Separator         a space character (of various non-zero widths)
        Zl  Line_Separator          U+2028 LINE SEPARATOR only
        Zp  Paragraph_Separator     U+2029 PARAGRAPH SEPARATOR only
        Z   Separator               Zs | Zl | Zp
        Cc  Control                 a C0 or C1 control code
        Cf  Format                  a format control character
        Cs  Surrogate               a surrogate code point
        Co  Private_Use             a private-use character
        Cn  Unassigned              a reserved unassigned code point or a noncharacter
        C   Other                   Cc | Cf | Cs | Co | Cn
    */
    /* Alpha Sorted
        Abbr    Long                Description
        C   Other                   Cc | Cf | Cs | Co | Cn
        Cc  Control                 a C0 or C1 control code
        Cf  Format                  a format control character
        Cn  Unassigned              a reserved unassigned code point or a noncharacter
        Co  Private_Use             a private-use character
        Cs  Surrogate               a surrogate code point
        L   Letter                  Lu | Ll | Lt | Lm | Lo
        LC  Cased_Letter            Lu | Ll | Lt
        Ll  Lowercase_Letter        a lowercase letter
        Lm  Modifier_Letter         a modifier letter
        Lo  Other_Letter            other letters, including syllables and ideographs
        Lt  Titlecase_Letter        a digraphic character, with first part uppercase
        Lu  Uppercase_Letter        an uppercase letter
        M   Mark                    Mn | Mc | Me
        Mc  Spacing_Mark            a spacing combining mark (positive advance width)
        Me  Enclosing_Mark          an enclosing combining mark
        Mn  Nonspacing_Mark         a nonspacing combining mark (zero advance width)
        N   Number                  Nd | Nl | No
        Nd  Decimal_Number          a decimal digit
        Nl  Letter_Number           a letterlike numeric character
        No  Other_Number            a numeric character of other type
        P   Punctuation             Pc | Pd | Ps | Pe | Pi | Pf | Po
        Pc  Connector_Punctuation   a connecting punctuation mark, like a tie
        Pd  Dash_Punctuation        a dash or hyphen punctuation mark
        Pe  Close_Punctuation       a closing punctuation mark (of a pair)
        Pf  Final_Punctuation       a final quotation mark
        Pi  Initial_Punctuation     an initial quotation mark
        Po  Other_Punctuation       a punctuation mark of other type
        Ps  Open_Punctuation        an opening punctuation mark (of a pair)
        S   Symbol                  Sm | Sc | Sk | So
        Sc  Currency_Symbol         a currency sign
        Sk  Modifier_Symbol         a non-letterlike modifier symbol
        Sm  Math_Symbol             a symbol of mathematical use
        So  Other_Symbol            a symbol of other type
        Z   Separator               Zs | Zl | Zp
        Zl  Line_Separator          U+2028 LINE SEPARATOR only
        Zp  Paragraph_Separator     U+2029 PARAGRAPH SEPARATOR only
        Zs  Space_Separator         a space character (of various non-zero widths)
    */

    Cc:'\u0000-\u001f\u007f-\u009f',
    Cf:'\u00ad\u0600-\u0603\u06dd\u070f\u17b4\u17b5\u200b-\u200f\u202a-\u202e\u2060-\u2063\u206a-\u206f\ufeff\ufff9-\ufffb',
    Co:'\ue000-\uf8ff',
    Cs:'\ud800\udb7f\udb80\udbff\udc00\udfff',
    Ll:'\u0061-\u007a\u00aa\u00b5\u00ba\u00df-\u00f6\u00f8-\u00ff\u0101\u0103\u0105\u0107\u0109\u010b\u010d\u010f\u0111\u0113\u0115\u0117\u0119\u011b\u011d\u011f\u0121\u0123\u0125\u0127\u0129\u012b\u012d\u012f\u0131\u0133\u0135\u0137\u0138\u013a\u013c\u013e\u0140\u0142\u0144\u0146\u0148\u0149\u014b\u014d\u014f\u0151\u0153\u0155\u0157\u0159\u015b\u015d\u015f\u0161\u0163\u0165\u0167\u0169\u016b\u016d\u016f\u0171\u0173\u0175\u0177\u017a\u017c\u017e-\u0180\u0183\u0185\u0188\u018c\u018d\u0192\u0195\u0199-\u019b\u019e\u01a1\u01a3\u01a5\u01a8\u01aa\u01ab\u01ad\u01b0\u01b4\u01b6\u01b9\u01ba\u01bd-\u01bf\u01c6\u01c9\u01cc\u01ce\u01d0\u01d2\u01d4\u01d6\u01d8\u01da\u01dc\u01dd\u01df\u01e1\u01e3\u01e5\u01e7\u01e9\u01eb\u01ed\u01ef\u01f0\u01f3\u01f5\u01f9\u01fb\u01fd\u01ff\u0201\u0203\u0205\u0207\u0209\u020b\u020d\u020f\u0211\u0213\u0215\u0217\u0219\u021b\u021d\u021f\u0221\u0223\u0225\u0227\u0229\u022b\u022d\u022f\u0231\u0233-\u0239\u023c\u023f\u0240\u0242\u0247\u0249\u024b\u024d\u024f-\u0293\u0295-\u02af\u037b-\u037d\u0390\u03ac-\u03ce\u03d0\u03d1\u03d5-\u03d7\u03d9\u03db\u03dd\u03df\u03e1\u03e3\u03e5\u03e7\u03e9\u03eb\u03ed\u03ef-\u03f3\u03f5\u03f8\u03fb\u03fc\u0430-\u045f\u0461\u0463\u0465\u0467\u0469\u046b\u046d\u046f\u0471\u0473\u0475\u0477\u0479\u047b\u047d\u047f\u0481\u048b\u048d\u048f\u0491\u0493\u0495\u0497\u0499\u049b\u049d\u049f\u04a1\u04a3\u04a5\u04a7\u04a9\u04ab\u04ad\u04af\u04b1\u04b3\u04b5\u04b7\u04b9\u04bb\u04bd\u04bf\u04c2\u04c4\u04c6\u04c8\u04ca\u04cc\u04ce\u04cf\u04d1\u04d3\u04d5\u04d7\u04d9\u04db\u04dd\u04df\u04e1\u04e3\u04e5\u04e7\u04e9\u04eb\u04ed\u04ef\u04f1\u04f3\u04f5\u04f7\u04f9\u04fb\u04fd\u04ff\u0501\u0503\u0505\u0507\u0509\u050b\u050d\u050f\u0511\u0513\u0561-\u0587\u1d00-\u1d2b\u1d62-\u1d77\u1d79-\u1d9a\u1e01\u1e03\u1e05\u1e07\u1e09\u1e0b\u1e0d\u1e0f\u1e11\u1e13\u1e15\u1e17\u1e19\u1e1b\u1e1d\u1e1f\u1e21\u1e23\u1e25\u1e27\u1e29\u1e2b\u1e2d\u1e2f\u1e31\u1e33\u1e35\u1e37\u1e39\u1e3b\u1e3d\u1e3f\u1e41\u1e43\u1e45\u1e47\u1e49\u1e4b\u1e4d\u1e4f\u1e51\u1e53\u1e55\u1e57\u1e59\u1e5b\u1e5d\u1e5f\u1e61\u1e63\u1e65\u1e67\u1e69\u1e6b\u1e6d\u1e6f\u1e71\u1e73\u1e75\u1e77\u1e79\u1e7b\u1e7d\u1e7f\u1e81\u1e83\u1e85\u1e87\u1e89\u1e8b\u1e8d\u1e8f\u1e91\u1e93\u1e95-\u1e9b\u1ea1\u1ea3\u1ea5\u1ea7\u1ea9\u1eab\u1ead\u1eaf\u1eb1\u1eb3\u1eb5\u1eb7\u1eb9\u1ebb\u1ebd\u1ebf\u1ec1\u1ec3\u1ec5\u1ec7\u1ec9\u1ecb\u1ecd\u1ecf\u1ed1\u1ed3\u1ed5\u1ed7\u1ed9\u1edb\u1edd\u1edf\u1ee1\u1ee3\u1ee5\u1ee7\u1ee9\u1eeb\u1eed\u1eef\u1ef1\u1ef3\u1ef5\u1ef7\u1ef9\u1f00-\u1f07\u1f10-\u1f15\u1f20-\u1f27\u1f30-\u1f37\u1f40-\u1f45\u1f50-\u1f57\u1f60-\u1f67\u1f70-\u1f7d\u1f80-\u1f87\u1f90-\u1f97\u1fa0-\u1fa7\u1fb0-\u1fb4\u1fb6\u1fb7\u1fbe\u1fc2-\u1fc4\u1fc6\u1fc7\u1fd0-\u1fd3\u1fd6\u1fd7\u1fe0-\u1fe7\u1ff2-\u1ff4\u1ff6\u1ff7\u2071\u207f\u210a\u210e\u210f\u2113\u212f\u2134\u2139\u213c\u213d\u2146-\u2149\u214e\u2184\u2c30-\u2c5e\u2c61\u2c65\u2c66\u2c68\u2c6a\u2c6c\u2c74\u2c76\u2c77\u2c81\u2c83\u2c85\u2c87\u2c89\u2c8b\u2c8d\u2c8f\u2c91\u2c93\u2c95\u2c97\u2c99\u2c9b\u2c9d\u2c9f\u2ca1\u2ca3\u2ca5\u2ca7\u2ca9\u2cab\u2cad\u2caf\u2cb1\u2cb3\u2cb5\u2cb7\u2cb9\u2cbb\u2cbd\u2cbf\u2cc1\u2cc3\u2cc5\u2cc7\u2cc9\u2ccb\u2ccd\u2ccf\u2cd1\u2cd3\u2cd5\u2cd7\u2cd9\u2cdb\u2cdd\u2cdf\u2ce1\u2ce3\u2ce4\u2d00-\u2d25\ufb00-\ufb06\ufb13-\ufb17\uff41-\uff5a',
    Lm:'\u02b0-\u02c1\u02c6-\u02d1\u02e0-\u02e4\u02ee\u037a\u0559\u0640\u06e5\u06e6\u07f4\u07f5\u07fa\u0e46\u0ec6\u10fc\u17d7\u1843\u1d2c-\u1d61\u1d78\u1d9b-\u1dbf\u2090-\u2094\u2d6f\u3005\u3031-\u3035\u303b\u309d\u309e\u30fc-\u30fe\ua015\ua717-\ua71a\uff70\uff9e\uff9f',
    Lo:'\u01bb\u01c0-\u01c3\u0294\u05d0-\u05ea\u05f0-\u05f2\u0621-\u063a\u0641-\u064a\u066e\u066f\u0671-\u06d3\u06d5\u06ee\u06ef\u06fa-\u06fc\u06ff\u0710\u0712-\u072f\u074d-\u076d\u0780-\u07a5\u07b1\u07ca-\u07ea\u0904-\u0939\u093d\u0950\u0958-\u0961\u097b-\u097f\u0985-\u098c\u098f\u0990\u0993-\u09a8\u09aa-\u09b0\u09b2\u09b6-\u09b9\u09bd\u09ce\u09dc\u09dd\u09df-\u09e1\u09f0\u09f1\u0a05-\u0a0a\u0a0f\u0a10\u0a13-\u0a28\u0a2a-\u0a30\u0a32\u0a33\u0a35\u0a36\u0a38\u0a39\u0a59-\u0a5c\u0a5e\u0a72-\u0a74\u0a85-\u0a8d\u0a8f-\u0a91\u0a93-\u0aa8\u0aaa-\u0ab0\u0ab2\u0ab3\u0ab5-\u0ab9\u0abd\u0ad0\u0ae0\u0ae1\u0b05-\u0b0c\u0b0f\u0b10\u0b13-\u0b28\u0b2a-\u0b30\u0b32\u0b33\u0b35-\u0b39\u0b3d\u0b5c\u0b5d\u0b5f-\u0b61\u0b71\u0b83\u0b85-\u0b8a\u0b8e-\u0b90\u0b92-\u0b95\u0b99\u0b9a\u0b9c\u0b9e\u0b9f\u0ba3\u0ba4\u0ba8-\u0baa\u0bae-\u0bb9\u0c05-\u0c0c\u0c0e-\u0c10\u0c12-\u0c28\u0c2a-\u0c33\u0c35-\u0c39\u0c60\u0c61\u0c85-\u0c8c\u0c8e-\u0c90\u0c92-\u0ca8\u0caa-\u0cb3\u0cb5-\u0cb9\u0cbd\u0cde\u0ce0\u0ce1\u0d05-\u0d0c\u0d0e-\u0d10\u0d12-\u0d28\u0d2a-\u0d39\u0d60\u0d61\u0d85-\u0d96\u0d9a-\u0db1\u0db3-\u0dbb\u0dbd\u0dc0-\u0dc6\u0e01-\u0e30\u0e32\u0e33\u0e40-\u0e45\u0e81\u0e82\u0e84\u0e87\u0e88\u0e8a\u0e8d\u0e94-\u0e97\u0e99-\u0e9f\u0ea1-\u0ea3\u0ea5\u0ea7\u0eaa\u0eab\u0ead-\u0eb0\u0eb2\u0eb3\u0ebd\u0ec0-\u0ec4\u0edc\u0edd\u0f00\u0f40-\u0f47\u0f49-\u0f6a\u0f88-\u0f8b\u1000-\u1021\u1023-\u1027\u1029\u102a\u1050-\u1055\u10d0-\u10fa\u1100-\u1159\u115f-\u11a2\u11a8-\u11f9\u1200-\u1248\u124a-\u124d\u1250-\u1256\u1258\u125a-\u125d\u1260-\u1288\u128a-\u128d\u1290-\u12b0\u12b2-\u12b5\u12b8-\u12be\u12c0\u12c2-\u12c5\u12c8-\u12d6\u12d8-\u1310\u1312-\u1315\u1318-\u135a\u1380-\u138f\u13a0-\u13f4\u1401-\u166c\u166f-\u1676\u1681-\u169a\u16a0-\u16ea\u1700-\u170c\u170e-\u1711\u1720-\u1731\u1740-\u1751\u1760-\u176c\u176e-\u1770\u1780-\u17b3\u17dc\u1820-\u1842\u1844-\u1877\u1880-\u18a8\u1900-\u191c\u1950-\u196d\u1970-\u1974\u1980-\u19a9\u19c1-\u19c7\u1a00-\u1a16\u1b05-\u1b33\u1b45-\u1b4b\u2135-\u2138\u2d30-\u2d65\u2d80-\u2d96\u2da0-\u2da6\u2da8-\u2dae\u2db0-\u2db6\u2db8-\u2dbe\u2dc0-\u2dc6\u2dc8-\u2dce\u2dd0-\u2dd6\u2dd8-\u2dde\u3006\u303c\u3041-\u3096\u309f\u30a1-\u30fa\u30ff\u3105-\u312c\u3131-\u318e\u31a0-\u31b7\u31f0-\u31ff\u3400\u4db5\u4e00\u9fbb\ua000-\ua014\ua016-\ua48c\ua800\ua801\ua803-\ua805\ua807-\ua80a\ua80c-\ua822\ua840-\ua873\uac00\ud7a3\uf900-\ufa2d\ufa30-\ufa6a\ufa70-\ufad9\ufb1d\ufb1f-\ufb28\ufb2a-\ufb36\ufb38-\ufb3c\ufb3e\ufb40\ufb41\ufb43\ufb44\ufb46-\ufbb1\ufbd3-\ufd3d\ufd50-\ufd8f\ufd92-\ufdc7\ufdf0-\ufdfb\ufe70-\ufe74\ufe76-\ufefc\uff66-\uff6f\uff71-\uff9d\uffa0-\uffbe\uffc2-\uffc7\uffca-\uffcf\uffd2-\uffd7\uffda-\uffdc',
    Lt:'\u01c5\u01c8\u01cb\u01f2\u1f88-\u1f8f\u1f98-\u1f9f\u1fa8-\u1faf\u1fbc\u1fcc\u1ffc',
    Lu:'\u0041-\u005a\u00c0-\u00d6\u00d8-\u00de\u0100\u0102\u0104\u0106\u0108\u010a\u010c\u010e\u0110\u0112\u0114\u0116\u0118\u011a\u011c\u011e\u0120\u0122\u0124\u0126\u0128\u012a\u012c\u012e\u0130\u0132\u0134\u0136\u0139\u013b\u013d\u013f\u0141\u0143\u0145\u0147\u014a\u014c\u014e\u0150\u0152\u0154\u0156\u0158\u015a\u015c\u015e\u0160\u0162\u0164\u0166\u0168\u016a\u016c\u016e\u0170\u0172\u0174\u0176\u0178\u0179\u017b\u017d\u0181\u0182\u0184\u0186\u0187\u0189-\u018b\u018e-\u0191\u0193\u0194\u0196-\u0198\u019c\u019d\u019f\u01a0\u01a2\u01a4\u01a6\u01a7\u01a9\u01ac\u01ae\u01af\u01b1-\u01b3\u01b5\u01b7\u01b8\u01bc\u01c4\u01c7\u01ca\u01cd\u01cf\u01d1\u01d3\u01d5\u01d7\u01d9\u01db\u01de\u01e0\u01e2\u01e4\u01e6\u01e8\u01ea\u01ec\u01ee\u01f1\u01f4\u01f6-\u01f8\u01fa\u01fc\u01fe\u0200\u0202\u0204\u0206\u0208\u020a\u020c\u020e\u0210\u0212\u0214\u0216\u0218\u021a\u021c\u021e\u0220\u0222\u0224\u0226\u0228\u022a\u022c\u022e\u0230\u0232\u023a\u023b\u023d\u023e\u0241\u0243-\u0246\u0248\u024a\u024c\u024e\u0386\u0388-\u038a\u038c\u038e\u038f\u0391-\u03a1\u03a3-\u03ab\u03d2-\u03d4\u03d8\u03da\u03dc\u03de\u03e0\u03e2\u03e4\u03e6\u03e8\u03ea\u03ec\u03ee\u03f4\u03f7\u03f9\u03fa\u03fd-\u042f\u0460\u0462\u0464\u0466\u0468\u046a\u046c\u046e\u0470\u0472\u0474\u0476\u0478\u047a\u047c\u047e\u0480\u048a\u048c\u048e\u0490\u0492\u0494\u0496\u0498\u049a\u049c\u049e\u04a0\u04a2\u04a4\u04a6\u04a8\u04aa\u04ac\u04ae\u04b0\u04b2\u04b4\u04b6\u04b8\u04ba\u04bc\u04be\u04c0\u04c1\u04c3\u04c5\u04c7\u04c9\u04cb\u04cd\u04d0\u04d2\u04d4\u04d6\u04d8\u04da\u04dc\u04de\u04e0\u04e2\u04e4\u04e6\u04e8\u04ea\u04ec\u04ee\u04f0\u04f2\u04f4\u04f6\u04f8\u04fa\u04fc\u04fe\u0500\u0502\u0504\u0506\u0508\u050a\u050c\u050e\u0510\u0512\u0531-\u0556\u10a0-\u10c5\u1e00\u1e02\u1e04\u1e06\u1e08\u1e0a\u1e0c\u1e0e\u1e10\u1e12\u1e14\u1e16\u1e18\u1e1a\u1e1c\u1e1e\u1e20\u1e22\u1e24\u1e26\u1e28\u1e2a\u1e2c\u1e2e\u1e30\u1e32\u1e34\u1e36\u1e38\u1e3a\u1e3c\u1e3e\u1e40\u1e42\u1e44\u1e46\u1e48\u1e4a\u1e4c\u1e4e\u1e50\u1e52\u1e54\u1e56\u1e58\u1e5a\u1e5c\u1e5e\u1e60\u1e62\u1e64\u1e66\u1e68\u1e6a\u1e6c\u1e6e\u1e70\u1e72\u1e74\u1e76\u1e78\u1e7a\u1e7c\u1e7e\u1e80\u1e82\u1e84\u1e86\u1e88\u1e8a\u1e8c\u1e8e\u1e90\u1e92\u1e94\u1ea0\u1ea2\u1ea4\u1ea6\u1ea8\u1eaa\u1eac\u1eae\u1eb0\u1eb2\u1eb4\u1eb6\u1eb8\u1eba\u1ebc\u1ebe\u1ec0\u1ec2\u1ec4\u1ec6\u1ec8\u1eca\u1ecc\u1ece\u1ed0\u1ed2\u1ed4\u1ed6\u1ed8\u1eda\u1edc\u1ede\u1ee0\u1ee2\u1ee4\u1ee6\u1ee8\u1eea\u1eec\u1eee\u1ef0\u1ef2\u1ef4\u1ef6\u1ef8\u1f08-\u1f0f\u1f18-\u1f1d\u1f28-\u1f2f\u1f38-\u1f3f\u1f48-\u1f4d\u1f59\u1f5b\u1f5d\u1f5f\u1f68-\u1f6f\u1fb8-\u1fbb\u1fc8-\u1fcb\u1fd8-\u1fdb\u1fe8-\u1fec\u1ff8-\u1ffb\u2102\u2107\u210b-\u210d\u2110-\u2112\u2115\u2119-\u211d\u2124\u2126\u2128\u212a-\u212d\u2130-\u2133\u213e\u213f\u2145\u2183\u2c00-\u2c2e\u2c60\u2c62-\u2c64\u2c67\u2c69\u2c6b\u2c75\u2c80\u2c82\u2c84\u2c86\u2c88\u2c8a\u2c8c\u2c8e\u2c90\u2c92\u2c94\u2c96\u2c98\u2c9a\u2c9c\u2c9e\u2ca0\u2ca2\u2ca4\u2ca6\u2ca8\u2caa\u2cac\u2cae\u2cb0\u2cb2\u2cb4\u2cb6\u2cb8\u2cba\u2cbc\u2cbe\u2cc0\u2cc2\u2cc4\u2cc6\u2cc8\u2cca\u2ccc\u2cce\u2cd0\u2cd2\u2cd4\u2cd6\u2cd8\u2cda\u2cdc\u2cde\u2ce0\u2ce2\uff21-\uff3a',
    Mc:'\u0903\u093e-\u0940\u0949-\u094c\u0982\u0983\u09be-\u09c0\u09c7\u09c8\u09cb\u09cc\u09d7\u0a03\u0a3e-\u0a40\u0a83\u0abe-\u0ac0\u0ac9\u0acb\u0acc\u0b02\u0b03\u0b3e\u0b40\u0b47\u0b48\u0b4b\u0b4c\u0b57\u0bbe\u0bbf\u0bc1\u0bc2\u0bc6-\u0bc8\u0bca-\u0bcc\u0bd7\u0c01-\u0c03\u0c41-\u0c44\u0c82\u0c83\u0cbe\u0cc0-\u0cc4\u0cc7\u0cc8\u0cca\u0ccb\u0cd5\u0cd6\u0d02\u0d03\u0d3e-\u0d40\u0d46-\u0d48\u0d4a-\u0d4c\u0d57\u0d82\u0d83\u0dcf-\u0dd1\u0dd8-\u0ddf\u0df2\u0df3\u0f3e\u0f3f\u0f7f\u102c\u1031\u1038\u1056\u1057\u17b6\u17be-\u17c5\u17c7\u17c8\u1923-\u1926\u1929-\u192b\u1930\u1931\u1933-\u1938\u19b0-\u19c0\u19c8\u19c9\u1a19-\u1a1b\u1b04\u1b35\u1b3b\u1b3d-\u1b41\u1b43\u1b44\ua802\ua823\ua824\ua827]',
    Me:'\u0488\u0489\u06de\u20dd-\u20e0\u20e2-\u20e4',
    Mn:'\u0300-\u036f\u0483-\u0486\u0591-\u05bd\u05bf\u05c1\u05c2\u05c4\u05c5\u05c7\u0610-\u0615\u064b-\u065e\u0670\u06d6-\u06dc\u06df-\u06e4\u06e7\u06e8\u06ea-\u06ed\u0711\u0730-\u074a\u07a6-\u07b0\u07eb-\u07f3\u0901\u0902\u093c\u0941-\u0948\u094d\u0951-\u0954\u0962\u0963\u0981\u09bc\u09c1-\u09c4\u09cd\u09e2\u09e3\u0a01\u0a02\u0a3c\u0a41\u0a42\u0a47\u0a48\u0a4b-\u0a4d\u0a70\u0a71\u0a81\u0a82\u0abc\u0ac1-\u0ac5\u0ac7\u0ac8\u0acd\u0ae2\u0ae3\u0b01\u0b3c\u0b3f\u0b41-\u0b43\u0b4d\u0b56\u0b82\u0bc0\u0bcd\u0c3e-\u0c40\u0c46-\u0c48\u0c4a-\u0c4d\u0c55\u0c56\u0cbc\u0cbf\u0cc6\u0ccc\u0ccd\u0ce2\u0ce3\u0d41-\u0d43\u0d4d\u0dca\u0dd2-\u0dd4\u0dd6\u0e31\u0e34-\u0e3a\u0e47-\u0e4e\u0eb1\u0eb4-\u0eb9\u0ebb\u0ebc\u0ec8-\u0ecd\u0f18\u0f19\u0f35\u0f37\u0f39\u0f71-\u0f7e\u0f80-\u0f84\u0f86\u0f87\u0f90-\u0f97\u0f99-\u0fbc\u0fc6\u102d-\u1030\u1032\u1036\u1037\u1039\u1058\u1059\u135f\u1712-\u1714\u1732-\u1734\u1752\u1753\u1772\u1773\u17b7-\u17bd\u17c6\u17c9-\u17d3\u17dd\u180b-\u180d\u18a9\u1920-\u1922\u1927\u1928\u1932\u1939-\u193b\u1a17\u1a18\u1b00-\u1b03\u1b34\u1b36-\u1b3a\u1b3c\u1b42\u1b6b-\u1b73\u1dc0-\u1dca\u1dfe\u1dff\u20d0-\u20dc\u20e1\u20e5-\u20ef\u302a-\u302f\u3099\u309a\ua806\ua80b\ua825\ua826\ufb1e\ufe00-\ufe0f\ufe20-\ufe23',
    Nd:'\u0030-\u0039\u0660-\u0669\u06f0-\u06f9\u07c0-\u07c9\u0966-\u096f\u09e6-\u09ef\u0a66-\u0a6f\u0ae6-\u0aef\u0b66-\u0b6f\u0be6-\u0bef\u0c66-\u0c6f\u0ce6-\u0cef\u0d66-\u0d6f\u0e50-\u0e59\u0ed0-\u0ed9\u0f20-\u0f29\u1040-\u1049\u17e0-\u17e9\u1810-\u1819\u1946-\u194f\u19d0-\u19d9\u1b50-\u1b59\uff10-\uff19',
    Nl:'\u16ee-\u16f0\u2160-\u2182\u3007\u3021-\u3029\u3038-\u303a',
    No:'\u00b2\u00b3\u00b9\u00bc-\u00be\u09f4-\u09f9\u0bf0-\u0bf2\u0f2a-\u0f33\u1369-\u137c\u17f0-\u17f9\u2070\u2074-\u2079\u2080-\u2089\u2153-\u215f\u2460-\u249b\u24ea-\u24ff\u2776-\u2793\u2cfd\u3192-\u3195\u3220-\u3229\u3251-\u325f\u3280-\u3289\u32b1-\u32bf',
    Pc:'\u005f\u203f\u2040\u2054\ufe33\ufe34\ufe4d-\ufe4f\uff3f',
    Pd:'\u002d\u058a\u1806\u2010-\u2015\u2e17\u301c\u3030\u30a0\ufe31\ufe32\ufe58\ufe63\uff0d',
    Pe:'\u0029\u005d\u007d\u0f3b\u0f3d\u169c\u2046\u207e\u208e\u232a\u2769\u276b\u276d\u276f\u2771\u2773\u2775\u27c6\u27e7\u27e9\u27eb\u2984\u2986\u2988\u298a\u298c\u298e\u2990\u2992\u2994\u2996\u2998\u29d9\u29db\u29fd\u3009\u300b\u300d\u300f\u3011\u3015\u3017\u3019\u301b\u301e\u301f\ufd3f\ufe18\ufe36\ufe38\ufe3a\ufe3c\ufe3e\ufe40\ufe42\ufe44\ufe48\ufe5a\ufe5c\ufe5e\uff09\uff3d\uff5d\uff60\uff63',
    Pf:'\u00bb\u2019\u201d\u203a\u2e03\u2e05\u2e0a\u2e0d\u2e1d',
    Pi:'\u00ab\u2018\u201b\u201c\u201f\u2039\u2e02\u2e04\u2e09\u2e0c\u2e1c',
    Po:'\u0021-\u0023\u0025-\u0027\u002a\u002c\u002e\u002f\u003a\u003b\u003f\u0040\u005c\u00a1\u00b7\u00bf\u037e\u0387\u055a-\u055f\u0589\u05be\u05c0\u05c3\u05c6\u05f3\u05f4\u060c\u060d\u061b\u061e\u061f\u066a-\u066d\u06d4\u0700-\u070d\u07f7-\u07f9\u0964\u0965\u0970\u0df4\u0e4f\u0e5a\u0e5b\u0f04-\u0f12\u0f85\u0fd0\u0fd1\u104a-\u104f\u10fb\u1361-\u1368\u166d\u166e\u16eb-\u16ed\u1735\u1736\u17d4-\u17d6\u17d8-\u17da\u1800-\u1805\u1807-\u180a\u1944\u1945\u19de\u19df\u1a1e\u1a1f\u1b5a-\u1b60\u2016\u2017\u2020-\u2027\u2030-\u2038\u203b-\u203e\u2041-\u2043\u2047-\u2051\u2053\u2055-\u205e\u2cf9-\u2cfc\u2cfe\u2cff\u2e00\u2e01\u2e06-\u2e08\u2e0b\u2e0e-\u2e16\u3001-\u3003\u303d\u30fb\ua874-\ua877\ufe10-\ufe16\ufe19\ufe30\ufe45\ufe46\ufe49-\ufe4c\ufe50-\ufe52\ufe54-\ufe57\ufe5f-\ufe61\ufe68\ufe6a\ufe6b\uff01-\uff03\uff05-\uff07\uff0a\uff0c\uff0e\uff0f\uff1a\uff1b\uff1f\uff20\uff3c\uff61\uff64\uff65',
    Ps:'\u0028\u005b\u007b\u0f3a\u0f3c\u169b\u201a\u201e\u2045\u207d\u208d\u2329\u2768\u276a\u276c\u276e\u2770\u2772\u2774\u27c5\u27e6\u27e8\u27ea\u2983\u2985\u2987\u2989\u298b\u298d\u298f\u2991\u2993\u2995\u2997\u29d8\u29da\u29fc\u3008\u300a\u300c\u300e\u3010\u3014\u3016\u3018\u301a\u301d\ufd3e\ufe17\ufe35\ufe37\ufe39\ufe3b\ufe3d\ufe3f\ufe41\ufe43\ufe47\ufe59\ufe5b\ufe5d\uff08\uff3b\uff5b\uff5f\uff62',
    Sc:'\u0024\u00a2-\u00a5\u060b\u09f2\u09f3\u0af1\u0bf9\u0e3f\u17db\u20a0-\u20b5\ufdfc\ufe69\uff04\uffe0\uffe1\uffe5\uffe6',
    Sk:'\u005e\u0060\u00a8\u00af\u00b4\u00b8\u02c2-\u02c5\u02d2-\u02df\u02e5-\u02ed\u02ef-\u02ff\u0374\u0375\u0384\u0385\u1fbd\u1fbf-\u1fc1\u1fcd-\u1fcf\u1fdd-\u1fdf\u1fed-\u1fef\u1ffd\u1ffe\u309b\u309c\ua700-\ua716\ua720\ua721\uff3e\uff40\uffe3',
    Sm:'\u002b\u003c-\u003e\u007c\u007e\u00ac\u00b1\u00d7\u00f7\u03f6\u2044\u2052\u207a-\u207c\u208a-\u208c\u2140-\u2144\u214b\u2190-\u2194\u219a\u219b\u21a0\u21a3\u21a6\u21ae\u21ce\u21cf\u21d2\u21d4\u21f4-\u22ff\u2308-\u230b\u2320\u2321\u237c\u239b-\u23b3\u23dc-\u23e1\u25b7\u25c1\u25f8-\u25ff\u266f\u27c0-\u27c4\u27c7-\u27ca\u27d0-\u27e5\u27f0-\u27ff\u2900-\u2982\u2999-\u29d7\u29dc-\u29fb\u29fe-\u2aff\ufb29\ufe62\ufe64-\ufe66\uff0b\uff1c-\uff1e\uff5c\uff5e\uffe2\uffe9-\uffec',
    So:'\u00a6\u00a7\u00a9\u00ae\u00b0\u00b6\u0482\u060e\u060f\u06e9\u06fd\u06fe\u07f6\u09fa\u0b70\u0bf3-\u0bf8\u0bfa\u0cf1\u0cf2\u0f01-\u0f03\u0f13-\u0f17\u0f1a-\u0f1f\u0f34\u0f36\u0f38\u0fbe-\u0fc5\u0fc7-\u0fcc\u0fcf\u1360\u1390-\u1399\u1940\u19e0-\u19ff\u1b61-\u1b6a\u1b74-\u1b7c\u2100\u2101\u2103-\u2106\u2108\u2109\u2114\u2116-\u2118\u211e-\u2123\u2125\u2127\u2129\u212e\u213a\u213b\u214a\u214c\u214d\u2195-\u2199\u219c-\u219f\u21a1\u21a2\u21a4\u21a5\u21a7-\u21ad\u21af-\u21cd\u21d0\u21d1\u21d3\u21d5-\u21f3\u2300-\u2307\u230c-\u231f\u2322-\u2328\u232b-\u237b\u237d-\u239a\u23b4-\u23db\u23e2-\u23e7\u2400-\u2426\u2440-\u244a\u249c-\u24e9\u2500-\u25b6\u25b8-\u25c0\u25c2-\u25f7\u2600-\u266e\u2670-\u269c\u26a0-\u26b2\u2701-\u2704\u2706-\u2709\u270c-\u2727\u2729-\u274b\u274d\u274f-\u2752\u2756\u2758-\u275e\u2761-\u2767\u2794\u2798-\u27af\u27b1-\u27be\u2800-\u28ff\u2b00-\u2b1a\u2b20-\u2b23\u2ce5-\u2cea\u2e80-\u2e99\u2e9b-\u2ef3\u2f00-\u2fd5\u2ff0-\u2ffb\u3004\u3012\u3013\u3020\u3036\u3037\u303e\u303f\u3190\u3191\u3196-\u319f\u31c0-\u31cf\u3200-\u321e\u322a-\u3243\u3250\u3260-\u327f\u328a-\u32b0\u32c0-\u32fe\u3300-\u33ff\u4dc0-\u4dff\ua490-\ua4c6\ua828-\ua82b\ufdfd\uffe4\uffe8\uffed\uffee\ufffc\ufffd',
    Zl:'\u2028',
    Zp:'\u2029',
    ZZ:'\u00a0\u1680\u180e\u2000-\u200a\u202f\u205f\u3000',
    Zs:'\u0020\u00a0\u1680\u180e\u2000-\u200a\u202f\u205f\u3000'
};

Unicode.C = Unicode.Cc 
            + Unicode.Cf 
            + Unicode.Cs 
            + Unicode.Co ;
            //+ Unicode.Cn ; //This is not defined.

Unicode.L = Unicode.Lu 
            + Unicode.Ll 
            + Unicode.Lt 
            + Unicode.Lm 
            + Unicode.Mn    //Added 2014-05-29 due to some letters in names not being recognized.
                            //This is where accent marks are individually combined instead of using an explicit character.
            + Unicode.Lo ;

Unicode.LC= Unicode.Lu 
            + Unicode.Ll 
            + Unicode.Lt ;

Unicode.M = Unicode.Mn 
            + Unicode.Mc 
            + Unicode.Me ;

Unicode.N = Unicode.Nd 
            + Unicode.Nl 
            + Unicode.No ;

Unicode.P = Unicode.Pc 
            + Unicode.Pd 
            + Unicode.Ps 
            + Unicode.Pe 
            + Unicode.Pi 
            + Unicode.Pf 
            + Unicode.Po ;

Unicode.S = Unicode.Sm 
            + Unicode.Sc 
            + Unicode.Sk 
            + Unicode.So ;

Unicode.Z = Unicode.Zs 
            + Unicode.Zl 
            + Unicode.Zp ;

//Not in Unicode spec:
Unicode.w = '_'
            + Unicode.L
            + Unicode.N ;

    //A Unicode based word boundry built with non-capturing parentheses
Unicode.b = '(?:[' + Unicode.w + '](?:[^' + Unicode.w +']|$)'
            + '|(?:^|[^' + Unicode.w + '])[' + Unicode.w +']'
            + ')' ;

    //A Unicode based word boundry build with non-capturing parentheses
Unicode.bOut = '(?=[^' + Unicode.w +']|$)';

    //A Unicode based word boundry build with non-capturing parentheses
    //JavaScript does not have a non-consuming look-behind.
    //This makes a direct replacement for \b not possible as we may consume
    // part of the string to make this test.
Unicode.bIn = '(?:^|[^' + Unicode.w + '])';

    //A possible work-around is to use a capture and replace it.
Unicode.bInCapture = '(?:^|([^' + Unicode.w + ']))';

    //A Unicode based non-word boundry build with non-capturing parentheses
Unicode.B = '(?:[' + Unicode.w + '][' + Unicode.w +']'
        + '|[^' + Unicode.w + '][^' + Unicode.w +']'
        + ')' ;

Unicode.d = Unicode.N ;
Unicode.uppercaseRegex      = new RegExp("[" + Unicode.Lu + "]", "");
Unicode.lowercaseRegex      = new RegExp("[" + Unicode.Ll + "]", "");
Unicode.titlecaseRegex      = new RegExp("[" + Unicode.Lt + "]", "");
Unicode.wordCharRegex       = new RegExp("[" + Unicode.w + "]", "");
Unicode.nonWordCharRegex    = new RegExp("[^" + Unicode.w + "]", "");
Unicode.letterAndSpaceRegEx = new RegExp("[^" + Unicode.L + Unicode.Zs + "]", "");
```