# javascript string.replace any language

Tags: javascript, regex

I try to wrap string with # hashtag character follow any language , below is my code after I add `u` shows error `Invalid flag supplied to RegExp constructor.`, how to solve it?

javascript

```
text.replace(/#([a-z0-9_\pL_]+)/igu, '<a href="'+url+'/$1">@$1</a>');
```

Comment: That might be because `u` is not a valid modifier?

Comment: Uh... by not passing `u`? JavaScript is Unicode-aware already.

Comment: but if I remove `u` only select english character

Comment: "*but if I remove u only select english character*" - but if you *add `u`* then it doesn't work at all, or select any character; because - as noted - it's both unnecessary and an invalid modifier.

Comment: @karthikmanchala but why the regex can't select other language string?

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't work? https://regex101.com/r/dC4yZ9/1

Comment: @DavidThomas after I remove `u` I still can't select other language string

Comment: @JasonSperske I did test in regex101 before but after I use in string.replace function then not work

Comment: @JasonSperske .. switch the flavor to javascript..

Comment: @vibskov check this out.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25968770/javascript-regex-accept-only-space-and-letters-from-all-languages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an approach that uses the [XRegExp](http://xregexp.com/) library (with the XRegExp Unicode Base add-on):

```js
var hashtags = XRegExp('#([a-z0-9_\\p{L}]+)', 'ig'),
    input = $('#input'),
    output = $('#output'),
    url = 'http://example.com';

input.on('keyup', function() {
    output.text(XRegExp.replace(input.val(), hashtags, '<a href="'+url+'/$1">@$1</a>'));
}).trigger('keyup');
```

```css
pre {
    white-space: pre-wrap;       /* CSS 3 */
    white-space: -moz-pre-wrap;  /* Mozilla, since 1999 */
    white-space: -pre-wrap;      /* Opera 4-6 */
    white-space: -o-pre-wrap;    /* Opera 7 */
    word-wrap: break-word;       /* Internet Explorer 5.5+ */
}
input {
  width: 98%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xregexp/2.0.0/xregexp-min.js"></script>
<script src="http://xregexp.com/addons/unicode/unicode-base.js"></script>

<label>Input:</label>
<input id='input' value='An example with #日本人 and #English but not #$%!'/><br>
<label>Output:</label>
<pre id='output'></pre>
```